# Swift - SpriteKit - Next Level Progress Bar

Tags: ios, swift, sprite

I would like to make a simple progress bar.  This would show total points and points required to reach the next level.
Lets say I have 100 points and Level 2 requires 1000points.  I would like my bar to increase by 10% and I can make a comment saying something like 100/1000points.
I presume that I'll have to use Sprites.  I have never used them before.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also make a progress bar just using UIKit components.
Here's a [link](https://github.com/AlNistor/vertical-progress-bar-swift), maybe it will help you.

Comment: Thanks Alexandru.

I managed to do one with UIKit using UIView.animate.  thanks.